# tensorflow for poets: “The name 'import/Mul' refers to an Operation not in the graph.”

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow

İ try to use tensorflow image retraining. 
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining

train like that and it is OK:

```
D:\dev\Anaconda\python D:/dev/detect_objects/tensorflow-master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py --image_dir D:/dev/detect_objects/flower_photos --bottleneck_dir D:/dev/detect_objects/tensorflow-master/retrain/bottleneck --architecture mobilenet_0.25_128 --output_graph D:/dev/detect_objects/tensorflow-master/retrain/output_graph/output.pb --output_labels D:/dev/detect_objects/tensorflow-master/retrain/output_labels/labels.txt --saved_model_dir D:/dev/detect_objects/tensorflow-master/retrain/saved_model_dir --how_many_training_steps 100
```

When predict new image like:

```
D:\dev\Anaconda\python D:/dev/detect_objects/tensorflow-master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py --graph=D:/dev/detect_objects/tensorflow-master/retrain/output_graph/output.pb  --labels=D:/dev/detect_objects/tensorflow-master/retrain/output_labels/labels.txt --image=D:/dev/detect_objects/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg
```

It gives error

```
KeyError: "The name 'import/Mul' refers to an Operation not in the graph."
```

label_image.py content:

```
  input_height = 299
  input_width = 299
  input_mean = 0
  input_std = 255
  #input_layer = "input"
  #output_layer = "InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1"

  input_layer = "Mul"
  output_layer = "final_result"
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
  input_height = 299
  input_width = 299
  input_mean = 0
  input_std = 255
  #input_layer = "input"
  #output_layer = "InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1"

  input_layer = "Mul"
  output_layer = "final_result"
```

to this:

```
   input_height = 128
   input_width = 128
   input_mean = 0
   input_std = 128
   input_layer = "input"
   output_layer = "final_result"
```

Comment: Oh okay, so you probably just knew the definitions of the mobilenet architecture provided by tensorflow-hub

Answer (score 0):

> If there is no node in the graph called "import/Mul" and we don't know
>   what the graph is or how it was produced, there's little chance that
>   anyone will be able to guess the right answer.

You might try printing the list of operations of your graph using `graph.get_operations()` and attempting to locate an appropriate-sounding node (try the first one that is printed)